# Can I give “translucence” to the sheet, with a nice color, rather than white?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

Can I give “translucence” to the sheet, with a nice color, rather than white? on this site hxxp://www.chaldean-catholic.org/ ,I am using Metro Genesis child Theme ..

I want to give like this hxxp://www.miguel-hidalgo.net/ or similar to this

Comment: That's rather cold..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
rgba(123,543,98, 0.5)
```

More info on css filters can be found at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/

Comment: Thanks fauverism for your help ,It is helpful

Answer (score 0):

The "rgba" color type can give transparency.  It stands for "Red Green Blue Alpha (transparency)."

Give the rgba color value, like this: "`rgba(redvalue,greenvalue,bluevalue,0.5)`."

The alpha transparency is 0 = transparent and 1 = no transparency.

Learn more about legal color values at [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp).

Comment: Thanks pianoman for your help ,It is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can set the opacity of an element using css. The answer from fauverism shows you how to do it with rgba (rgb + alpha) colors. The alpha is how transparent the color is.

You can also set this with the css property `opacity` and is supported from IE9+. As far as off white goes.. you can try this:

```
elementName {
    color: #ddd;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

[Here's the MDN resource on opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help ,It is helpful

Comment: Make sure you accept one of these answers so others can see your question was properly answered.